# Which compression utility should I use for an extremely large plain text file?

Tags: linux, command-line, data, file-compression, hpc

I have a lot of data.  A **lot**.  My data file is a little under 2TB (terabytes) of line-separated plain text records, each about 4 or 5 KB (totaling to a few hundred million records).

I'm prioritizing compression ratio, stream-ability, and decompression speed.  More specifically:

- I expect to compress this data once, then read from it many times.
- I do not expect this data to change.  I may acquire new data later, but that's a separate problem.
- All reads from this file will be in sequential order, usually (but not always) from the beginning to the end of the file.
- I want to back up this data somewhere.  It took a long time to acquire, and I *do not* plan on doing it again.
- I do not expect to uncompress this file in its entirety; only to the extent needed to pipe its contents to another program.
- I don't care about preserving file metadata.

This on a Linux HPC cluster, so I'm looking for a command-line utility.  My main contenders are `gzip`, `bzip2`, and `lzma`, but I'm open to other options. It's okay if I have to compile software myself, as long as I don't need root access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>I've decided to go with [Zstandard](https://facebook.github.io/zstd).  I don't have exact numbers on hand, but this suits my compression needs the best, with `xz` a close second.  Compression times are reasonable, but I don't need to decompress my data any faster than I can process it.</s>

Changed my mind, [7zip](https://www.7-zip.org) is even better for my needs.  Here's what I did.

## My Data

About 2TB of line-separated JSON objects.  In other words, lots and lots of plain text.

## The Command

This is the exact command I'm using to compress my data, annotated:

`7z a -t7z -ms=on -myx=9 -mx=9 -mf=off -m0=PPMd:mem2g:o32 "$INPUT.7z" "$INPUT"`

Now, what these mean...

- `7z`: The command-line tool.
- [`a`](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/commands/add.htm): **A**dds a file to an archive (or creates if it if doesn't already exist)
- [`-t7z`](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/type): Use an archive of **t**ype **7z** (as opposed to `gz`, `bzip2`, `lzma`, etc.)
- [`-m`](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/method): Use these **m**ethods in compresing:

  - [`s=on`](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/method#Solid): Turn **on** **s**olid mode.  Might not be relevant since I'm compressing one large file (as opposed to a big group of smaller ones), but why not?
  - [`yx=9`](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/method#SevenZipYX): Do the most file analysis.
  - [`x=9`](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/method#SevenZipX): Use the most powerful compression available.
  - [`f=off`](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/method#Filter): Turn compression **f**iltering **off**.  This is mainly for executable files, which I'm not processing.
  - [`0=PPMd:mem2g:o32`](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/method#MethodID): Use the following parameters for the **first** (and in my case, only) compression method.

    - [`PPMd`](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/method#PPMd): Use the PPMd algorithm, which is said to provide a "very good compression ratio for plain text files."
    - [`mem2g`](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/method#MemorySize): Use 2GB of RAM for compression and decompression.
    - [`o32`](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/method#Order): Use a model **o**rder of 32.  I don't honestly know what this implies, I just set it to the highest value because it felt good.
- `"$INPUT.7z"`: The archive I'm creating.
- `"$INPUT"`: The file I'm storing in the archive.

## The Difference

I compressed a 219 GB subset of my data with several different programs to see which one got the best results.  I wasn't benchmarking time or memory, only size.  Here's what I got:

- **Original File**: 234,645,370,989 bytes (219 GB)
- **7zip, compressed as above**: 7,201,531,161 bytes (6.8 GB)
- [**zstd**](https://facebook.github.io/zstd): 7,438,787,613 bytes (7 GB)

  - Command: `zstd -k -T0 -22 --ultra "$INPUT" -o "$INPUT.zst"`
- [**lrzip**](https://github.com/ckolivas/lrzip): 8,531,295,280 bytes (8 GB)

  - Command: `lrzip --zpaq --level=9 --maxram=40 --threads=$(nproc) -T -U "$INPUT" -o "$INPUT.lrz"`
- **bzip2:** 20,016,871,549 bytes (19 GB)

  - Command: `bzip2 --best --keep --stdout "$INPUT" > "$INPUT.bz2"`
- **gzip**: 28,807,716,394 bytes (27 GB)

  - Command: `gzip --best --stdout "$INPUT" > "$INPUT.gz"`
- [**lz4**](https://lz4.github.io/lz4): 32,455,506,529 bytes (31 GB)

  - Command: `lz4 -9 -BD "$INPUT" "$INPUT.lz4"`
- [**lzop**](https://www.lzop.org): 34,197,587,319 bytes (32 GB)

  - Command: `lzop --best --keep "$INPUT"`

Comment: in other words: benchmark! the [turbobench](https://github.com/powturbo/TurboBench) tool might help. interesting results: compressed size, cpu time for compression and decompression, memory usage for compression and decompression, speed of random file access in a multi-file archive

Comment: PPMd compression is 3x faster than xz, but PPMd decompression is 20x slower than xz, based on my data (text files)

Answer (score 1):

I would seriously consider taking a look at the [HDF5 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_Data_Format) as it is specifically designed for this sort of use-case. Details of supported compression formats can be found [here](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/faq/compression.html) but include pre-defined ZLIB and SZIP plus several 3rd party options.

The reference software includes a number of language bindings and there are bindings for python available via pip.

Comment: It looks like HDF5 is primarily for numerical data?  My data isn't really numerical, it's textual.

Comment: @JesseTG: HDF5 can combine almost any data types, e.g. https://www.hdfgroup.org/portfolio-item/medicine/ where images, metadata, text & numbers are all being stored.

Comment: And which utility is it, exactly?  I'm only finding documentation for the C/C++ APIs (which are not what I want right now).